# Helm dependencies tags issue

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following value in values.yaml, and changes are made on the deployment side depending on the situation.

```
test:
  test1: false
  default: true
```

```
ingress-nginx:
  enabled: true
tags:
  test.default: true
```

I don't want the dependencies in the Chart.yaml file to install when I set test1 to true. But no matter what I did it didn't work.

```
dependencies:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    version: "4.0"
    repository: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
    condition: ingress-nginx.enabled
    tags:
      - test.default: true
      - test.test1: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm doesn't support Boolean logic in the dependency setup.  The only [supported conditions](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#tags-and-condition-fields-in-dependencies) are:

1. If `dependencies:` contains a `condition:`, that names a path into the values structure, and if it is true then the dependency is installed.  If more than one path is specified in a comma-separated string, the first path that exists is used; if none of the paths exist, go to 2.
2. Otherwise, if `dependencies:` contains `tags:` and the values do as well, then if any of the values' tags matching the dependencies' tags are `true`, install the dependency.

In both cases, the logic is "if something is true then install the dependency".  There is no way to tell Helm to install a dependency only if a value is false.  In your example, since there's a `condition:`, that will usually take precedence (unless the `ingress-nginx: { enabled: }` values doesn't exist at all).

The easiest thing to do here is just use that `enabled` value.  There are multiple sources of values, including the `helm install --set` option and additional values files passed via `helm install -f`; the chart's `values.yaml` file is used mostly as defaults.  So you can set this dependency to "on" in the chart's values

```yaml
# values.yaml
ingress-nginx:
  enabled: true
```

but then have an add-on "profile" values that disables it

```yaml
# test1.yaml
ingress-nginx:
  enabled: false
```

and specify that additional values file when you install the chart

```bash
helm install myapp . -f test1.yaml
```

If you did want to use `tags:` here then you'd need to invert the value of the tag.  In the `dependencies:` section you'd specify the inverted tag name as a string, and omit the `condition:`

```yaml
# Chart.yaml
dependencies:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    tags:
      - not-test1
    # no condition:
```

In the top-level values file, you'd specify some default for it, probably "on"

```yaml
# values.yaml
tags:
  not-test1: true
```

Then when you install the chart, you can disable this.  (An override values file as in the previous example would also work.)

```bash
helm install myapp . --set tags.not-test1=false
```