# Helm subchart enable based on flag negation

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a gobal values flag which when disabled, I would like to enable a sub chart and vice versa. Helm provides conditions but it does not provide negation. The flag definition already exists in product so can't change it. Any suggestions on how to achieve this.
Also, can I derive a new value from the existing flag and negate it and then use it in conditions

I expect the helm conditions to solve this or any other way would do as well

Comment: This isn't an option in Helm.  `condition:` has a very limited expression language and doesn't support negation at all.  In addition to the [linked question](/q/64807093) I've written a little bit more about what is and isn't possible in response to [Helm dependencies tags issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419988/helm-dependencies-tags-issue).