# Control (Enable/Disable) sub chart dependencies based one helm property

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to achieve kind of if-else condition in helm (if the flag is enabled: true, install app1, or if the flag is enabled: false, install app2).

I see there is no straight forward option in helm, also experimented something with tags (obviously tags serves different purpose: same tags in many sub charts to enable them together), not working as expected.

I am quite to new helm, please guide me

**something like this**

**values.yaml**

```
flag:
 enabled: true
```

**requirements.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  - name: app1
    condition: flag.enabled //true
    version: 1.1.0
    repository: https://myhelmrepo
  - name: app2
    condition: !flag.enabled //false
    version: 1.1.0
    repository: https://myanotherhelmrepo
```

**tried with tags**

**values.yaml**

```
flag:
 enabled: true
tags:
 app1: true
 app2: false
```

**requirements.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  - name: app1
    condition: flag.enabled
    version: 1.1.0
    repository: https://myhelmrepo
    tags:
    - app1
  - name: app2
    version: 1.1.0
    repository: https://myanotherhelmrepo
    condition: flag.enabled
    tags:
    - app2
```

Comment: Helm doesn't support this; `condition:` and `tags:` only work to install something if a value is true, but not false and not complex Boolean logic.  [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75420496/10008173) to [Helm dependencies tags issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419988/helm-dependencies-tags-issue) also might help clarify what's possible.